# Docker container returns Connection refused when trying to connect to database MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

When I try to execute my app.py it gives me an Internal Server Error saying connection has been refused. My MongoDB is running, my credentials are right and if I go to 192.168.56.5:27017 I get the usual trying to access MongoDB over native driver port.

Code of my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_URI'] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/SC"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    collection =  mongo.db.People.find({},{"lastname":1})
    for name in collection:
        lastname = name['lastname']
    return render_template('index.html', title='Welcome', achternaam=lastname)
```

I have an init-mongo.js with my User in it, role admin and db SC.

Code to my docker-compose.yml of mongo container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongoSC'
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=SC
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=gianni
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
  volumes:
    - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
    - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
  ports:
    - '27017-27019:27019'
```

What I have tried:
localhost:27017/SC
192.168.56.5:27017/SC
192.168.56.5:27019/SC
0.0.0.0:27017/SC
mongodb://Gianni:secret@127.0.0.1:27017/SC
127.0.0.1:27017/SC
pymongo.MongoClient("192.168.56.5:27017")
pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:27017")

I have connection in Robo 3T using the 192.168.56.5:27017. It doesn't seem to work in my app.py, I could use some help with this. Hopefully I have provided enough code!

[Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAluC.png)

Comment: Your port syntax looks wrong and that might be causing connection issues. If you specify a range of ports (e.g. `27017-27019`) you have to use equivalent ranges for host can container: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#ports

Comment: would it be better here to just use 27017 and go with that?

Comment: yes, I'd try that

Comment: Where you set `app.config['MONGO_URI']` in your flask app, the hostname for the mongo container should be `database` rather than `localhost`, as that's what you've called the service in your compose file; thus a special DNS alias is available.  Also there's no need to specify `ports` for that database service in the compose file, as ports are not restricted between services.  The only reason to do this would be to expose the database on the host's interface.

Comment: I have managed to fix the connection by using mongodb://Gianni:123@192.168.56.5:27017/SC. I have got a second problem now which says I have no authentication. Do I make a new question for this or can this be answered in this comment section? If so, I have the user with admin already made and tried a lot of other options like MongoClient, --auth in docker-compose, other first result google options to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the error message? Please don't paste images.